# Javascript Pretty Print Format is giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, json, pretty-print

```js
function output(inp) {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
  }


  function searchInGitRepo(str) {
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + str);
    http.send();
    http.onload = () => {
      var result = http.responseText;
      var strformat = JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4);
      output(strformat);
    }
  }

  var result = searchInGitRepo('ecommerce');
```

I want to get data from `github` reponsitories. Result is coming perfectly but data is not formatting. Please take a look my code. It should work. I have followed many solution. Nothing is working for me!

```
function searchInGitRepo(str) {
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + str);
    http.send();
    http.onload = () => {
      var result = http.responseText;
      var strformat = JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4);
      output(strformat);
    }
}
```

Output Function:

```
function output(inp) {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` is used to convert objects into strings. It's usually used when sending data to a web server because those data has to be a string.

In your case, the data `result` that you are getting back from the server are already `string`, thus you don't need to "stringify" it.

Use `output(result);` instead of `output(strformat);`

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: I added an explanation for you if you are interested

Comment: Got it. Thank you.